# FireDac Cached updates stops updating

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I am using SQLite databases (Delphi Seattle) FireDac components.
I have more than two applications writing into tables of the same database.
I was getting lock issues therefore started using CachedUpdates and all was fine.

Problem:
At times when the Application is running for more than few hours the Application stops Updating (Edit, Delete) my database tables, Read (Select) works fine.
No error comes up in OnReconcileError. This issue takes place in one of the applications and at the same time the other application using the same database works fine.
If problematic application is restarted, all is well again.

This is how I open my databases

```
LockingMode=Normal
StringFormat=Unicode
JournalMode=WAL
DriverID=SQLite
SharedCache=False
Synchronous=Full
BusyTimeout=20000
ForeignKeys=Off
```

Typical pattern of writing

```
  try
    wQry:=TFDQuery.Create(Nil);
    wQry.Connection:=form_DatabaseWork.FDConnection1 ;
    wQry.CachedUpdates:=True ;
    wQry.Active:=false;
    wQry.sql.text:='Select * from Setups';
    wQry.Active:=True;
    wQry.Edit ;
    wQry.FieldByName('DisplayTitles').AsString:=wMsg ;
    ssPost(wQry) ;
    ssApplyUpdates(wQry);
  finally
    wQry.Active:=false;
    FreeAndNil(wQry);
  end;
```

Called functions

```
procedure ssApplyUpdates(pQry:TFDQuery);
var
  nErr:Integer ;
begin
  nErr:=pQry.ApplyUpdates ;
  if nErr>0 then
  begin
    pQry.OnReconcileError:=form_Tools.Qry_DummyReconcileError ;
    pQry.Reconcile ;
    pQry.OnReconcileError:=Nil ;
  end
  else
    pQry.CommitUpdates ;
end;

function ssPost(pQry:TFDQuery):Boolean ;
begin
  result:=false;
  try
    pQry.Post;
    result:=true;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteSomewhere(E.Message) ;
  end;
end;

procedure Tform_Tools.Qry_DummyReconcileError(DataSet: TFDDataSet; E: EFDException; UpdateKind: TFDDatSRowState; var Action: TFDDAptReconcileAction);
begin
  Action:=raCorrect ; 
end;
```

I have not added FDconnection.transaction ... Hope that will help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing your code so that the flow of execution follows the example in the section `Applying Updates` [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Caching_Updates_(FireDAC)#Samples0)

Comment: This could not happen. FireDAC has a very stable code for internal storage (inspired by .NET). No matter how long it's running.

Comment: A common cause of behavior like this is starting an explicit transaction which blocks other clients from seeing changes until the transaction is committed. For sqlite that would be  a `begin;` without a following `commit;` or `rollback;`.

Comment: @Brian, that would not explain this issue.

Comment: @TLama Updates complete without error but other sessions or connections don't see the updates. ....  that is the pattern of an outer active transaction not yet committed. May not be the issue in this case but it does follow the pattern.

Comment: @Brian, I don't know exactly what's happening inside as I don't have Delphi by hand right now. but I'm fairly sure the internal storage is written very well. One does not lose data if something bad happens with DBMS.

Comment: I have added the transaction handling. All the same I do not know if this will help. @Brian, I had not used transactions at all so there was no question of pending transaction.